# What is the d3.js v4.0 equivalent for d3.scale.category10()?

Tags: d3.js

I'm trying to learn d3 with the Interactive Web Visualization book, but a lot has changed with version 4.0. One thing I really can't figure out is if there is an equivalent for d3.scale.category10() to get an easy mapping to colors. Is there something like that in the new version or do we need to use math.random and code up something ourselves?

Answer (score 164, accepted):

Instead of

```
d3.scale.category10()
```

use

```
d3.scaleOrdinal(d3.schemeCategory10);
```

Create a color scale like this:

```
var color = d3.scaleOrdinal(d3.schemeCategory10);
```

use the color like this in the code same as in V3:

```
svg.append("rect")
.attr("x", 10)
.attr("y", 10)
.attr("width", 100)
.attr("height", 100)
.style("fill", color(3))
```

read [here](https://github.com/d3/d3-scale/blob/master/README.md#schemeCategory10)

Reference [here](https://github.com/d3/d3-scale/issues/63)

working code [here](https://plnkr.co/edit/KCu3HsHrA2dYvZaM0RCQ?p=preview)

Comment: Thanks! I was just scrolling through the change document and finally found the explanation.

Comment: No matter what number you supply to `color()`, in your working code, the output is always blue and orange - is that the expected behaviour? What if I want purple?

Comment: This seems to be a solution, to what I was expecting: `color = d3.scaleOrdinal(d3.schemeCategory10).domain(d3.range(0, 9));`

Comment: ` in your working code, the output is always blue and orange - is that the expected behaviour?` No thats not expected i am getting green here https://plnkr.co/edit/2DzxaDg1SjidDkz5v2P4?p=preview

Answer (score 3):

A straight-forward solution is to use the following color scales in version-4 of d3.js :

```
var colorScale_1 = d3.schemeCategory10;
var colorScale_2 = schemeCategory20;
var colorScale_3 = d3.schemeCategory20b;
var colorScale_4 = d3.schemeCategory20c;
```

colorScale_1, colorScale_2, colorScale_3, colorScale_4 are the arrays of different colors. So, you can use their different indices to fill the shape. For example

```
svg.append("rect")
.attr("x", 10)
.attr("y", 10)
.attr("width", 100)
.attr("height", 100)
.style("fill", colorScale_1[2])
```

For reference, take a look here: http://bl.ocks.org/emmasaunders/f4902478bcfa411c77a412c02087bed4

Hope that helps.