# Need help importing D3 radar chart into react component

Tags: javascript, react-native, svg, d3.js, scale

I have a radar chart working in a regular js file, and a react app component that can render and return a simple bar chart. I'm trying to get the much more complex radar chart to render and return in react's component. I'm currently getting an error: `./src/App.js Attempted import error: 'scale' is not exported from 'd3' (imported as 'd3').` Any other feedback/suggestions in general would be appreciated. I'm new to D3. Thanks so much in advance.

```
import * as d3 from "d3";
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.state = {};
 }
  
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
/////////////// The Radar Chart Function ////////////////
/////////////// Written by Nadieh Bremer ////////////////
////////////////// VisualCinnamon.com ///////////////////
/////////// Inspired by the code of alangrafu ///////////
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

/* Radar chart design created by Nadieh Bremer - VisualCinnamon.com */



 componentDidMount() {
 //////////////////////// Set-Up //////////////////////////////
 
 var margin = { top: 100, right: 100, bottom: 100, left: 100 },
   width = Math.min(700, window.innerWidth - 10) - margin.left - margin.right,
   height = Math.min(
     width,
     window.innerHeight - margin.top - margin.bottom - 20
   );
 
 ////////////////////////// Data //////////////////////////////
 
 var data = [
   [
     //Tsircon
     { axis: "BALLISTIC", value: 65 },
     { axis: "Glide", value: 39 },
     { axis: "20G TURN", value: 43 },
     { axis: "FISH HOOK DIVE", value: 50 },
     { axis: "PHUGOID MOTION", value: 60 },
     { axis: "ENERGY SCRUB", value: 52 },
   ],
   //   [
   //     //Kinzhal
   //     { axis: "BALLISTIC", value: 0.27 },
   //     { axis: "Glide", value: 0.16 },
   //     { axis: "20G TURN", value: 0.35 },
   //     { axis: "FISH HOOK DIVE", value: 0.13 },
   //     { axis: "PHUGOID MOTION", value: 0.2 },
   //     { axis: "ENERGY SCRUB", value: 0.13 },
   //   ],
   //   [
   //     //Example Missile Overlay
   //     { axis: "BALLISTIC", value: 0.26 },
   //     { axis: "Glide", value: 0.1 },
   //     { axis: "20G TURN", value: 0.3 },
   //     { axis: "FISH HOOK DIVE", value: 0.14 },
   //     { axis: "PHUGOID MOTION", value: 0.22 },
   //     { axis: "ENERGY SCRUB", value: 0.04 },
   //   ],
 ];
 //////////////////// Draw the Chart //////////////////////////
 
 var color = d3.scale.ordinal().range(["#739CC4", "#CC333F", "#00A0B0"]);
 
 var radarChartOptions = {
   w: width,
   h: height,
   margin: margin,
   maxValue: 0.5,
   levels: 5,
   roundStrokes: false,
   color: color,
 };
 //Call function to draw the Radar chart
 RadarChart(".radarChart", data, radarChartOptions);
 
 function RadarChart(id, data, options) {
   var cfg = {
     w: 600, //Width of the circle
     h: 600, //Height of the circle
     margin: { top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 20, left: 20 }, //The margins of the SVG
     levels: 3, //How many levels or inner circles should there be drawn
     maxValue: 0, //What is the value that the biggest circle will represent
     labelFactor: 1.25, //How much farther than the radius of the outer circle should the labels be placed
     wrapWidth: 60, //The number of pixels after which a label needs to be given a new line
     opacityArea: 0.35, //The opacity of the area of the blob
     dotRadius: 4, //The size of the colored circles of each blog
     opacityCircles: 0.1, //The opacity of the circles of each blob
     strokeWidth: 2, //The width of the stroke around each blob
     roundStrokes: false, //If true the area and stroke will follow a round path (cardinal-closed)
     color: d3.scale.category10(), //Color function
   };
 
   //Put all of the options into a variable called cfg
   if ("undefined" !== typeof options) {
     for (var i in options) {
       if ("undefined" !== typeof options[i]) {
         cfg[i] = options[i];
       }
     } //for i
   } //if
 
   //If the supplied maxValue is smaller than the actual one, replace by the max in the data
   var maxValue = Math.max(
     cfg.maxValue,
     d3.max(data, function (i) {
       return d3.max(
         i.map(function (o) {
           return o.value;
         })
       );
     })
   );
 
   var allAxis = data[0].map(function (i, j) {
       return i.axis;
     }), //Names of each axis
     total = allAxis.length, //The number of different axes
     radius = Math.min(cfg.w / 2, cfg.h / 2), //Radius of the outermost circle
     Format = d3.format("%"), //Percentage formatting
     angleSlice = (Math.PI * 2) / total; //The width in radians of each "slice"
 
   //Scale for the radius
   var rScale = d3.scale.linear().range([0, radius]).domain([0, maxValue]);
 
   //////////// Create the container SVG and g /////////////
 
   //Remove whatever chart with the same id/class was present before
   d3.select(id).select("svg").remove();
 
   //Initiate the radar chart SVG
   var svg = d3
     .select(id)
     .append("svg")
     .attr("width", cfg.w + cfg.margin.left + cfg.margin.right)
     .attr("height", cfg.h + cfg.margin.top + cfg.margin.bottom)
     .attr("class", "radar" + id);
   //Append a g element
   var g = svg
     .append("g")
     .attr(
       "transform",
       "translate(" +
         (cfg.w / 2 + cfg.margin.left) +
         "," +
         (cfg.h / 2 + cfg.margin.top) +
         ")"
     );
 
   ////////// Glow filter ///////////
 
   //Filter for the outside glow
   var filter = g.append("defs").append("filter").attr("id", "glow"),
     feGaussianBlur = filter
       .append("feGaussianBlur")
       .attr("stdDeviation", "2.5")
       .attr("result", "coloredBlur"),
     feMerge = filter.append("feMerge"),
     feMergeNode_1 = feMerge.append("feMergeNode").attr("in", "coloredBlur"),
     feMergeNode_2 = feMerge.append("feMergeNode").attr("in", "SourceGraphic");
 
   /////////////// Draw the Circular grid //////////////////
 
   //Wrapper for the grid & axes
   var axisGrid = g.append("g").attr("class", "axisWrapper");
 
   //Draw the background circles
   axisGrid
     .selectAll(".levels")
     .data(d3.range(1, cfg.levels + 1).reverse())
     .enter()
     .append("circle")
     .attr("class", "gridCircle")
     .attr("r", function (d, i) {
       return (radius / cfg.levels) * d;
     })
     .style("fill", "#CDCDCD")
     .style("stroke", "#CDCDCD")
     .style("fill-opacity", cfg.opacityCircles)
     .style("filter", "url(#glow)");
 
   //Text indicating at what % each level is
   axisGrid
     .selectAll(".axisLabel")
     .data(d3.range(1, cfg.levels + 1).reverse())
     .enter()
     .append("text")
     .attr("class", "axisLabel")
     .attr("x", 4)
     .attr("y", function (d) {
       return (-d * radius) / cfg.levels;
     })
     .attr("dy", "0.4em")
     .style("font-size", "10px")
     .attr("fill", "#737373")
     .text(function (d, i) {
       return Format((maxValue * d) / cfg.levels);
     });
 
   //////////////////// Draw the axes //////////////////////
 
   //Create the straight lines radiating outward from the center
   var axis = axisGrid
     .selectAll(".axis")
     .data(allAxis)
     .enter()
     .append("g")
     .attr("class", "axis");
   //Append the lines
   axis
     .append("line")
     .attr("x1", 0)
     .attr("y1", 0)
     .attr("x2", function (d, i) {
       return rScale(maxValue * 1.1) * Math.cos(angleSlice * i - Math.PI / 2);
     })
     .attr("y2", function (d, i) {
       return rScale(maxValue * 1.1) * Math.sin(angleSlice * i - Math.PI / 2);
     })
     .attr("class", "line")
     .style("stroke", "white")
     .style("stroke-width", "2px");
 
   //Append the labels at each axis
   axis
     .append("text")
     .attr("class", "legend")
     .style("font-size", "11px")
     .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
     .attr("dy", "0.35em")
     .attr("x", function (d, i) {
       return (
         rScale(maxValue * cfg.labelFactor) *
         Math.cos(angleSlice * i - Math.PI / 2)
       );
     })
     .attr("y", function (d, i) {
       return (
         rScale(maxValue * cfg.labelFactor) *
         Math.sin(angleSlice * i - Math.PI / 2)
       );
     })
     .text(function (d) {
       return d;
     })
     .call(wrap, cfg.wrapWidth);
 
     svg.append("text")
         .attr("x", (width / 4.8))             
         .attr("y", 75 - (margin.top / 2))
         .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
         .style("font-size", "24px") 
         .style("font-weight", "bold")
         .style("fill", "white")  
         .text("MANEUVERS");
 
     svg.append("text")
         .attr("x", (width / 4.2))             
         .attr("y", 95 - (margin.top / 2))
         .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
         .style("font-size", "16px") 
         .style("fill", "white")  
         .text("initiate: % ground track");
 
     svg.append("text")
         .attr("x", (width / 3.6))             
         .attr("y", 115 - (margin.top / 2))
         .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
         .style("font-size", "16px") 
         .style("fill", "#8CD9FF")  
         .text("% variability");
 
     svg.append("text")
         .attr("x", (width / 8))             
         .attr("y", 135 - (margin.top / 2))
         .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
         .style("font-size", "16px") 
         .style("fill", "white")  
         .text("sample:");
 
     svg.append("text")
         .attr("x", (width / 3.4))             
         .attr("y", 135 - (margin.top / 2))
         .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
         .style("font-size", "16px") 
         .style("fill", "#76ADDB")  
         .text("% trajectories");
 
   ///////////// Draw the radar chart blobs ////////////////
 
   //The radial line function
   var radarLine = d3.svg.line
     .radial()
     .interpolate("linear-closed")
     .radius(function (d) {
       return rScale(d.value);
     })
     .angle(function (d, i) {
       return i * angleSlice;
     });
 
   if (cfg.roundStrokes) {
     radarLine.interpolate("cardinal-closed");
   }
 
   //Create a wrapper for the blobs
   var blobWrapper = g
     .selectAll(".radarWrapper")
     .data(data)
     .enter()
     .append("g")
     .attr("class", "radarWrapper");
 
   //Append the backgrounds
   blobWrapper
     .append("path")
     .attr("class", "radarArea")
     .attr("d", function (d, i) {
       return radarLine(d);
     })
     .style("fill", function (d, i) {
       return cfg.color(i);
     })
     .style("fill-opacity", cfg.opacityArea)
     .on("mouseover", function (d, i) {
       //Dim all blobs
       d3.selectAll(".radarArea")
         .transition()
         .duration(200)
         .style("fill-opacity", 0.1);
       //Bring back the hovered over blob
       d3.select(this).transition().duration(200).style("fill-opacity", 0.7);
     })
     .on("mouseout", function () {
       //Bring back all blobs
       d3.selectAll(".radarArea")
         .transition()
         .duration(200)
         .style("fill-opacity", cfg.opacityArea);
     });
 
   //Create the outlines
   blobWrapper
     .append("path")
     .attr("class", "radarStroke")
     .attr("d", function (d, i) {
       return radarLine(d);
     })
     .style("stroke-width", cfg.strokeWidth + "px")
     .style("stroke", function (d, i) {
       return cfg.color(i);
     })
     .style("fill", "none")
     .style("filter", "url(#glow)");
 
   //Append the circles
   blobWrapper
     .selectAll(".radarCircle")
     .data(function (d, i) {
       return d;
     })
     .enter()
     .append("circle")
     .attr("class", "radarCircle")
     .attr("r", cfg.dotRadius)
     .attr("cx", function (d, i) {
       return rScale(d.value) * Math.cos(angleSlice * i - Math.PI / 2);
     })
     .attr("cy", function (d, i) {
       return rScale(d.value) * Math.sin(angleSlice * i - Math.PI / 2);
     })
     .style("fill", function (d, i, j) {
       return cfg.color(j);
     })
     .style("fill-opacity", 0.8);
 
   //////// Append invisible circles for tooltip ///////////
 
   //Wrapper for the invisible circles on top
   var blobCircleWrapper = g
     .selectAll(".radarCircleWrapper")
     .data(data)
     .enter()
     .append("g")
     .attr("class", "radarCircleWrapper");
 
   //Append a set of invisible circles on top for the mouseover pop-up
   blobCircleWrapper
     .selectAll(".radarInvisibleCircle")
     .data(function (d, i) {
       return d;
     })
     .enter()
     .append("circle")
     .attr("class", "radarInvisibleCircle")
     .attr("r", cfg.dotRadius * 1.5)
     .attr("cx", function (d, i) {
       return rScale(d.value) * Math.cos(angleSlice * i - Math.PI / 2);
     })
     .attr("cy", function (d, i) {
       return rScale(d.value) * Math.sin(angleSlice * i - Math.PI / 2);
     })
     .style("fill", "none")
     .style("pointer-events", "all")
     .on("mouseover", function (d, i) {
       newX = parseFloat(d3.select(this).attr("cx")) - 10;
       newY = parseFloat(d3.select(this).attr("cy")) - 10;
 
       tooltip
         .attr("x", newX)
         .attr("y", newY)
         .text(Format(d.value))
         .transition()
         .duration(200)
         .style("opacity", 1);
     })
     .on("mouseout", function () {
       tooltip.transition().duration(200).style("opacity", 0);
     });
 
   //Set up the small tooltip for when you hover over a circle
   var tooltip = g.append("text").attr("class", "tooltip").style("opacity", 0);
 
   /////////////////// Helper Function /////////////////////
 
   //Taken from http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/7555321
   //Wraps SVG text
   function wrap(text, width) {
     text.each(function () {
       var text = d3.select(this),
         words = text.text().split(/\s+/).reverse(),
         word,
         line = [],
         lineNumber = 0,
         lineHeight = 1.4, // ems
         y = text.attr("y"),
         x = text.attr("x"),
         dy = parseFloat(text.attr("dy")),
         tspan = text
           .text(null)
           .append("tspan")
           .attr("x", x)
           .attr("y", y)
           .attr("dy", dy + "em");
 
       while ((word = words.pop())) {
         line.push(word);
         tspan.text(line.join(" "));
         if (tspan.node().getComputedTextLength() > width) {
           line.pop();
           tspan.text(line.join(" "));
           line = [word];
           tspan = text
             .append("tspan")
             .attr("x", x)
             .attr("y", y)
             .attr("dy", ++lineNumber * lineHeight + dy + "em")
             .text(word);
         }
       }
     });
   } //wrap
 } //RadarChart
} //componentDidMount
    render() {
      const styles = {
        container: {
          display: "grid",
          justifyItems: "center"
        }
      };
    return (
      // <div ref="chart" style={styles.container}>
      <div className=".radarChart" style={styles.container}>
        <h1 style={{ textAlign: "center" }}>Hi, I'm the radar chart</h1>
      </div>
     );
   }
  }
export default App;
```

Edit: update: so I found some answers elsewhere, thank you @Michael Rovinsky for pointing me in the right direction. Some of this code was pre D3 version 4.

[d3.scale.linear() vs d3.scaleLinear()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35953892/d3-scale-linear-vs-d3-scalelinear)

[What is the d3.js v4.0 equivalent for d3.scale.category10()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38391411/what-is-the-d3-js-v4-0-equivalent-for-d3-scale-category10)

Current error: I am now getting

```
src\App.js
  Line 406:8:   'newX' is not defined  no-undef
  Line 407:8:   'newY' is not defined  no-undef
  Line 410:21:  'newX' is not defined  no-undef
  Line 411:21:  'newY' is not defined  no-undef
```

Which was fixed by defining them with "let" so the new code is
`let newX = parseFloat(d3.select(this).attr("cx")) - 10; let newY = parseFloat(d3.select(this).attr("cy")) - 10;`

Finally I was getting an error `TypeError: Cannot read property 'radial' of undefined`

which was solved by updating `var radarLine = d3.svg.line.radial().interpolate("linear-closed").radius(...`
to `radarLine = d3.lineRadial().radius(...`

The graph rendered once I fixed the typo className=".radarChart" to className="radarChart"

Comment: What is the D3 version you use? `d3.scale.xxx` functions are outdated

Comment: "d3": "^6.7.0", so it looks like the latest version. Are there replacement functions, or something else?

Comment: Replace `d3.scale.ordinal` with `d3.scaleBand`

Comment: `d3.scale.linear` with `d3.scaleLinear`

Comment: regarding `d3.scale.category10` - do you really need it?

Comment: I just saw your replies, sorry. Ok, I updated and we are making progress! I'm now getting these newX and newY is not defined errors. 

As for the scale.category10, it now reads ```d3.scaleBand(d3.schemeCategory10)``` and I am not sure if I need it or not.

Comment: try `const newX = parseFloat(...`, `const newY = parseFloat(...`

Comment: I just tried that and it worked (sorry, stackOverflow won't let me edit a comment quickly enough)

I'm now getting ```TypeError: Cannot read property 'radial' of undefined
```

```var radarLine = d3.svg.line
     .radial()
     .interpolate("linear-closed")
     .radius(function (d) {
       return rScale(d.value);
     })```

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/232784/discussion-between-evanpoe-and-michael-rovinsky).